# Can I find solutions to $a^4 + a^2 + a = b^2 + b$, $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $ 1 < a < b$?

Tags: polynomials, integer-programming, integers

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the correct direction
for either finding a solution to my problem or proving that it does not exist.

$$a^4 + a^2 + a = b^2 + b \;\text{ for }\; a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \;\text{ and }\; 1 < a < b$$

To be honest I don't really believe there is a solution 
(my brute force program yielded no solutions). But how
do I prove this in the general sense? If you don't have time to provide
a proof a nod in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Like some people pointed out, I make a mistake in the
initial question, the constraints on a and b should be: $1 < a < b$ instead of $1 < b < a$. I have fixed the question to reflect this change.

Comment: Do you really mean $1 < b < a$? It's more interesting if you say $1 < a < b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write the equation as $$a=(b-a^2)(b+a^2+1).$$ But if $b$ is positive the right factor $b+a^2+1$ is strictly greater than $a$, so equality can never be attained.

Comment: Currently the only answer that solves OP's edited question.

Comment: Neat.  But there is an answer by @hunter (which was deleted yesterday) which did address the question with exactly this condition.  A pity the OP didn't take care.

Comment: @Macavity Thanks. But why was it deleted then?

Comment: Because the question was different then!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $a^4+a^2+a > a^2+a > b^2+b$ if $a > b> 1$

Comment: Irrelevant answer now that the question has been changed.

Comment: @user314 making such a mistake / changing the question 1 day later perhaps is the bigger issue. Not particularly tempted to revise it now, maybe we should wait longer and see if the new question changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution because $$a^4+a^2+a>b^2+b$$
Indeed,
$$a^2+a>b^2+b$$

Comment: Irrelevant answer now that the question has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
$a > 1, b = \frac{1}2\left(\sqrt{4a^4+4a^2+4a+1}-1\right)$.

Comment: $b$ has to be an integer, so this will work when and only when $4a^4+4a^2+4a+1$ is a perfect square.